# Efficient approach for solving matrix plus diagonal matrix system that varies in time

Tags: ode, linear-solver

When solving a system of ODEs, as part of a preconditioner, I get the system

$(A + D(t))x = b(t)$

where $A$ is a sparse matrix and $D(t)$ is diagonal. I'm currently solving this by taking the LU-decomposition of the system for each $t$. $A$ is constant throughout the solution.

Is there an algorithm that would allow me to solve this efficiently without recomputing a decomposition at every step?

Comment: I see some possibilities, but more information is needed from you. How accurately do you need to compute $x$? Are you using GMRES? Does $D$ and $b$ change slowly over time? What properties does $A$ have? What can you tell us about the original problem. Depending on your answers it may be fruitful to recycle preconditioners and/or Krylov subspaces and extrapolate initial guesses.

Comment: @CarlChristian OP writes that they are solving this system "as part of a preconditioner", so I assume they are interested in direct methods.

Comment: Ideally, I would be interested in a direct method; however, I can tolerate some inaccuracy in the solution. $A$ is the first order terms of a mass-action network. It has some very large off-diagonal terms. $D(t)$ captures second order terms of the mass-action network which have a special form for the problem I'm working on. $D(t)$ and $b(t)$ can change quickly. I'm using GMRES as part of the SUNDIALS suite.

Comment: This is actually a frequently asked question: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/503 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5101 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2917 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10630 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2400 and the answer appears to be that there is no known way to use the fixed+diagonal structure.

Comment: @Kirill. I believe that you are trying help by strengthening the case against the fixed + diagonal structure. However, as this is OP's very first question here, I think we should mention that of the questions listed are all at least 5 years old, are not in the context of an ODE and do not include a time-dependence. It is precisely these differences which provide some options.

Comment: @CarlChristian I think you might be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe that a direct solve is possible in your situation, there are simply *too* many applications with *too* many users which would benefit *too* much if it was possible. In particular, the problem of computing, say, the transfer function $T(s) = C(A - sI)^{-1}B+D$ of a linear time invariant system 
$$ \begin{align} x'(t) &= Ax(t) + Bu(t) \\ y (t) &= Cx(t) + Du(t) \end{align}$$
or solving the Lyapunov matrix equation 
$$AX + XA^T = BB^T$$ 
using the alternating direction implicit (ADI) method would be greatly facilitated by any algorithm which would allows to pass cheaply from a factorization of $A$ to a factorization of $A - sI$.

On the off chance that $D(t)$ has low rank, then the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula would allow you to quickly solve systems with coefficient matrix $A + D(t)$ provided you can quickly solve system with coefficient matrix $A$. However, I gather that this is not likely.

I suggest that you view the solution $x$ of your linear system $$(A + D(t)) x = b(t)$$ as a function of $t$. It is likely that $x$ can be differentiate a few times with respect to $t$ which suggests that future values of $x$ can be extrapolated from past values. In particular, if $h$ is small enough, then 
$$ x_0 = x(t), \quad \text{or}\quad x_0 = 2x(t) - x(t-h)$$
represent simple and easy to implement initial guesses for the value of $x(t+h)$. More sophisticated approximation are possible, but they are not necessarily worth the effort.

I suggest further that your solve your linear system using a preconditioned Krylov subspace method. Instead of computing a new preconditioner for every timestep, I suggest that you recycle the preconditioner a few times and compute a new preconditioner only when the current one appears ineffective, i.e., the iteration count becomes too large.

I cannot promise that these options will give you the speed you are looking for, but at least they provide some parameters which can be tuned: the choice of the initial guess, the preconditioner and the number of time-steps before you compute a new preconditioner.

Answer (score 1):

No (unless $D$ has few nonzeros). Variants of this question get asked a lot here, and the answer is invariably the same.

Comment: Direct links to at least some of the very similar questions: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/503 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5101 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2917 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10630 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2400